# How to bypass legacy code in sonarQube analysis?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarlint

we have a legacy code (10 years old), I want to bypass that code not to be analyzed in SonarQube. Or, SonarQube should scan only recent changes which i made to the legacy code or new files. How to achieve this. I found the CutOff Plugin is deprecated since SonarQube4.0 , we are using SonarQube 7.5
Please help

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) documentation page? See also the [Fixing the water leak](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.5/user-guide/fixing-the-water-leak/) page.

Answer (score 0):

SonarScanner doesn't support analyzing only part of source code (example: only newer than a specified date). It always scans everything. If you keep your legacy code in other packages than the new code, then you may configure exclusion filter to just ignore the old code. You have to set the `sonar.exclusions` parameter (comma-separated list with ignored paths). You can read more about [Narrowing the Focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.5/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) in the official documentation.

Be aware that the proposed solution is not recommended. SonarScanner is able to find many vulnerabilities which should be fixed also in legacy code. It can prevent your company against material (e.g. money) and non-material (reputation) losses. The recommended way is to scan all code, and use Quality Gate to prevent introducing new issues. You can read more about it in [Fixing the Water Leak](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.5/user-guide/fixing-the-water-leak/).